# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in a Wordpress Template

Tags: php, parsing, syntax, brackets

I am troubleshooting "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else'" and I think the problem has to do with my brackets. I am new to php, so I can't quite figure out what is going wrong here. This is a wordpress page template that would check to see if the user is logged in... if not, it would display a message saying you need to login in order to see the page. Here is the code for the .php template that is creating the problem:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Logged-In Users Page
*/
?>
<!--?php if(is_user_logged_in()):?-->
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <?php
    $sidebar_position = get_post_meta( get_queried_object_id(), 'vw_page_sidebar_position', true );
    $sidebar_position_class = '';
    if ( 'left' == $sidebar_position ) {
    $sidebar_position_class = 'sidebar-left';
    } else if( 'right' == $sidebar_position ) {
    $sidebar_position_class = 'sidebar-right';
    } else {
    $sidebar_position_class = 'sidebar-hidden';
    }
    ?>

<div id="page-wrapper" class="container <?php echo $sidebar_position_class; ?>">
<div class="row">
    <div id="page-content" class="col-sm-7 col-md-8">
        <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php get_template_part( 'templates/page-title' ); ?>

                <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'clearfix' ); ?>>
                    <?php get_template_part( 'templates/post-formats/format', get_post_format() ); ?>
                    <div class="post-content"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
                </article>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'templates/pagination' ); ?>

            <?php comments_template(); ?>

        <?php else : ?>

            <h2><?php _e('Not Found', 'envirra') ?></h2>

        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>

    <?php if ( 'left' == $sidebar_position || 'right' == $sidebar_position ) : ?>
    <aside id="page-sidebar" class="sidebar-wrapper col-sm-5 col-md-4">
        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    </aside>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
<?php else:
wp_die('Sorry, you must first <a href="/wp-login.php">log in</a> to view this page. You can <a href="/wp-login.php?action=register">register free here</a>.');
endif; ?>
```

Comment: What line #? The error should say

Comment: `<?php else : ?>` missing its opening equivalent. `<?php if (condtion):?>` - if not using it, remove it.

Comment: Rather this `<?php else:
wp_die...`

Answer (score 3):

You've commented out the first part of this if statement:

```
<!--?php if(is_user_logged_in()):?-->
```

It should be:

```
<?php if(is_user_logged_in()):?>
```

Alternatively, delete the part at the end:

```
<?php else:
wp_die('Sorry, you must first <a href="/wp-login.php">log in</a> to view this page. You can <a href="/wp-login.php?action=register">register free here</a>.');
endif; ?>
```